# C# Performance Impact of Async function calling async function

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I was writing code where I ended up calling async method from another async method. I was wondering about performance impact of this practice. Does it leads to using so many threads for each async-await ?

An example would help

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ControllerMethod() 
{
    :
    return await A1();
}

public async Task<R1> A1() 
{
    :
    var result = await A2();
    if (result != null) 
    {  
        A3() 
    }
    return result;
}

public async Task<R1> A2() 
{
    :
    var result = await A4();
    return result;
}

public void A3() 
{
    :
    // call to another async method without await
}
```

Please help me understand - is this bad practice ? This was result of refactoring code

Comment: Obligatory link when someone asks about performance: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: "Does it lead to using so many threads...?" What threads? [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) as far as I can see in your code.

Comment: Depending on framework you are using, it will most likely land on ThreadPool Thread and get added into a queue, so no additional threads will be created. All threads that you need are already launched when you start your application.

Comment: Don't confuse async with multithreading. It's not the same thing.

Comment: Let me try to ask other way - Is there negative performance impact if I break a large async method to many small ones

Comment: Please [edit] your question to ask your new question if you have one. But if you read the article linked by @DavidG, you'll find that the best way of measuring performance is to run the code and measure the performance. We can't do that for you.

Comment: I would be cautious about `A3`. `async void` methods can be dangerous if not used correctly, and the places they can be used correctly are very very few.  Without any code in there in your example, it is hard to say for sure though.

Comment: Thanks Bradley. A3() is setting result asynchronously in cache, and I did not want to wait for it to complete before returning back result to caller

Answer (score 1):

The cost and performance impact lays into the fact that each method that gets marked as async gets transferred into a statemachine behind the scenes; so more code and statemachine instances that must be taken care of.

You can avoid a statemachine with a rewrite as here below; you don’t have to await if there is no code following that statement, just return the task as done in the A2 method below.

```
public Task<IHttpActionResult> ControllerMethod() 
{
    return A1();
}

public async Task<R1> A1() 
{
    var result = await A2();
    if (result !=  null)
    {  
        A3() 
    }
    return result;
}

public Task<R1> A2() 
{
    return A4();
}

public void A3() 
{
    // call to another async method without await
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all a bad practice. This is the opposite if the small methods that you're breaking down into does some work that really needs async operations. Suppose in the method **A4()** you're reading data from a file(A non-CPU binding operation that doesn't need any thread from your ASP .NET thread-pool). If you don't use async in this operation, you're thread will be stuck with the operation doing nothing while the data is being read from the file.

On the contrary, if you use async, the thread will return to the thread-pool, and the thread-pool will be able to serve more request with that newly freed thread.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt you can always test the results. In this benchmark all methods are executing the same code. The only difference is that in some I execute everything on one method and on others I split it into multiple methods.

```cs
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Test
{
    [Benchmark]
    public async Task TestWithoutCallingOtherMethod()
    {
        // call an async method to make this method async
        await Task.Delay(0);

        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();

        // function to be extracted ----------------------------------
        int sum = 0;
        // call an async method to make this method async
        await Task.Delay(0);
        foreach (var bt in guid)
            sum += bt;
        // -----------------------------------------------------------

        // will never happen. Include so compiler does not complain
        if (sum == 100000)
            throw new Exception();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public async Task TestCallingAnotherMethod()
    {
        // call an async method to make this method async
        await Task.Delay(0);

        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();

        if (await sumBytes(guid) == 1000000)
            throw new Exception();
    }

    async Task<int> sumBytes(byte[] guid)
    {
        // call an async method to make this method async
        await Task.Delay(0);

        int sum = 0;
        foreach (var bt in guid)
            sum += bt;

        return sum;
    }


    [Benchmark]
    public async Task TestCallingAnotherMethodThatIsStatic()
    {
        // call an async method to make this method async
        await Task.Delay(0);

        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();

        if (await sumBytesStatic(guid) == 1000000)
            throw new Exception();
    }

    static async Task<int> sumBytesStatic(byte[] guid)
    {
        // call an async method to make this method async
        await Task.Delay(0);

        int sum = 0;
        foreach (var bt in guid)
            sum += bt;

        return sum;
    }
}
```

And this where the results:

```
|                               Method |     Mean |   Error |  StdDev |  Gen 0 | Allocated |
|------------------------------------- |---------:|--------:|--------:|-------:|----------:|
|        TestWithoutCallingOtherMethod | 343.5 ns | 1.23 ns | 1.02 ns |      - |      40 B |
|             TestCallingAnotherMethod | 345.6 ns | 6.31 ns | 5.27 ns | 0.0010 |     112 B |
| TestCallingAnotherMethodThatIsStatic | 341.9 ns | 3.09 ns | 4.12 ns |      - |     112 B |
```

This results shows that it is practically the same.